# How to select and check these types of checkboxes based on values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

```
<span class="answerBox">
<a name="checkboxtag" class="largecheckbox" onclick="selectQuestionAnswer(this);"></a>
<input name="answers" value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c" class="checkbox displaynone" type="radio">
</span>
```

I've tried using .prop()

```
jQuery('input:checkbox[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Tried to just trigger a click:

```
jQuery('input:checkbox[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').trigger('click');
```

Tried editing its sibling's class (because on click, it changes the sibling's class and nothing else):

```
jQuery('input:checkbox[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').siblings('.largecheckbox').trigger('click');
```

Then I wasn't so sure if I was even selecting it correctly. I tried to toggle highlight on the checkbox but it doesn't do anything..

```
jQuery('input:checkbox[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').siblings('.largecheckbox').toggle('highlight');
jQuery('input:checkbox[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').toggle('highlight');
```

Is it just not possible to select this checkbox? I've been trying all day yesterday and today.

Thanks for reading and any help!

Edit: you guys are gods. IT WORKS. I used `jQuery('input:radio[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').siblings().toggle('highlight');`

to just make sure it worked AND IT DOES. THANK YOU.
Then I used trigger('click'); and it **did**. All I had to do was select it using the radio selector. Thank you everyone for your efforts.

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in your html

Comment: That makes a lot of sense...

Comment: Yes, did you understand what I said?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try to select it with a radio selector now. Wasn't expecting such quick responses and editing my question is wonky (sorry I'm new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change an `<input type="radio">` with a checkbox selector

Fix one or the other to what it is supposed to be

Your code works fine when you change to

```
<input name="answers" value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c" type="checkbox">
```

If you want to leave as radio use `:radio` selector

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/od5wx0f0/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, after you change the radio to checkbox.

```
$(function(){
    $(".largecheckbox").click(function(){
        $(this).next("input:checkbox").attr("checked",true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution was very close. Just change the colon to a period.

```
jQuery('input.checkbox[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function to check any checkbox you need to pass jquery object of the checkbox

```
function toggleCheck(elm, checked) {
    if (elm.is(":checked") != checked) {
        elm.click();
    }
}

toggleCheck($('[name="answers]'), true) // will check if not already checked
toggleCheck($('[name="answers]'), false) // will un check if already checked
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a matching element，to be `changed$('input:radio[value="8ad6a4124641ec5001464d856b23436c"]')`，